# how to speed up extracting domain from a url?

Tags: python, performance, dictionary

I have the below script which opens a file that contains two columns ip,domain

```
e.g 108.170.206.91|.com.invitemedia.prod2.pixel
```

and tries first to revered domain name because it is in fns form and then via public suffix module extract the second level domain

```
`e.g invitemedia.com`
```

It works well but it is a bit slow, can somebody help me to make it faster?

Here is my  script:

```
psl = PublicSuffixList()
d = {}
f = open(file, 'r')
for n, line in enumerate(f):
    ip,reversed_domain_1= line.split('|')
    try:
        reversed_domain_2 = reversed_domain_1.split('.')
        reversed_domain_3 = list(reversed(reversed_domain_2))
        domain = ('.'.join(reversed_domain_3)).strip('.')
        domain = psl.get_public_suffix(domain)
        assert domain
    if ip in d:
        d[ip].add(domain)
    else:
        d[ip] = set([domain])

    except:
       print (domain)
        continue
 for ip,domain in d.iteritems(): 
      print("%s|%d" % (ip, domain), file = output)
```

Comment: what does you input look like, you seem to be doing a lot of method calls? I would forget about reversed and just split then join . `spl = ".com.google.mail.www".split(".")".".join((spl[1:][::-1]))`

Comment: for line in f: print ".".join(line.split('|')[1].split('.')[1:3][::-1])

Comment: Split does not work here cause the length of domain level (number of dots ) are different

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a default dict for the `d` variable you are handling. You might also have better performance if you do a slice rather than `reverse` and similar.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(set) # You can now treat it like every key is always present

...

domain = '.'.join(input.split('.')[2:0:-1])
```

The default dict means you do not need to check that a key is present before handling it:

```
d = defaultdict(set)
d[1].add(2)
```

Comment: can you elaborate more on the advantage of default key here? I did not understand completely. and I think the slice thing is not applicable because I do not know the domain level (how many dot may be there)

Comment: You stated that you wanted the second level domain, giving the example of `invitemedia.com` from `.com.invitemedia.prod2.pixel`. So I assumed that you always wanted the first two elements. (reviewing this just now I realise I had the slice backwards heh)

Comment: The collections framework describes itself as "high performance container datatypes" so `defaultdict` is at least no worse than your existing code and may be better. See https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html

Comment: Thanks for your explanation about defaultdict, I understood. The reason why I used this reversed is that, I do not know what would be the TLD because it can be something.com or something.co.uk or something.com.au etc

Comment: In that situation you might want to use `reduce` or similar to consume each part of the domain name until an acceptable top level domain + sub domain is formed. Example: https://gist.github.com/matthewfranglen/35063119469ed61dbd31

Comment: but isn't that more complicated that publicsuffix module that I am using (it has the list of TLDs and it extracts second level domain name from high level domains names)

Comment: You haven't described that class in any way. It may be better to use that.

Answer (score 1):

Your code refers to a (presumably) global `psl` which you don't provide any details about. I presume that isn't where the performance is proving unsatifactory.

There's no need for the `list()` call, as the `join()` string method will handle the returned iterator perfectly well.

Is the `strip()` call strictly necessary? Its presence implies that your data contains leading and/or trailing dots. If this is indeed the case then you'll get a (probably miniscule) speed-up by stripping before you split `reversed_domain_`1` rather than after.

The advice by [@Matthew Franglen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/170865/matthew-franglen) about using `collections.defaultdict` will also help speed your code up.